# Is school/work a valid excuse for missing jummah

Tags: salat, jumuah

I'm currently still in school and am not allowed out unless it's lunch time (which occurs before jummah) and because of this I am forced to miss jummah more than 3 times in a row. Am I a kafir of Fasiq because of this?

I go to jummah everytime when I do not have school (holidays etc.).

Comment: A few years ago, I had a class on Fridays. It happened to be around 1:00- 2:00, which was Juma time in the state I was living in. I told my professor that I would be late for class on Fridays and explained the reason behind it. He happily accepted my excuse and said that it wasn't a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are not a kaafir for not praying Jummah three times in a row. The Hadith you are talking about says that Allah (SWT) will put a seal over his heart, which basically means that he will become heedless to the guidance of Allah (SWT), may Allah save us from that.

> It was narrated on the authority of Abu Hurayrah and ‘Abdullaah Ibn ‘Umar  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  them   that the Prophet , threatened the one who leaves the Friday prayer that Allaah The Exalted would close his heart and thus, he would become one of the heedless. [Muslim]
>
> It was narrated on the authority of Abu Al-Ja‘d Adh-Dhamri  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him that the Messenger of Allaah , said that whoever misses three consecutive Friday prayers out of negligence will have a seal put over his heart by Allaah The Almighty to prevent it from receiving guidance. [At-Tirmithi] [source][1](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=8571)

Attending jummah prayer is obligatory and one cannot leave it unless he has Shareah approved reasons, which don't include going to school, studying, etc. [https://islamqa.info/en/36530]. Allah (SWT) says in the Quran:

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا إِذَا نُودِيَ لِلصَّلَاةِ مِن يَوْمِ الْجُمُعَةِ فَاسْعَوْا إِلَىٰ ذِكْرِ اللَّهِ وَذَرُوا الْبَيْعَ ۚ ذَٰلِكُمْ خَيْرٌ لَّكُمْ إِن كُنتُمْ تَعْلَمُونَ
>
> O you who have believed, when [the adhan] is called for the prayer on the day of Jumu'ah [Friday], then proceed to the remembrance of Allah and leave trade. That is better for you, if you only knew. 62:09

I'd recommend that you talk to your professor and explain the situation to him. I am sure he will give you permission. If not, you should obey Allah (SWT) as obeying the Creator takes precedence over all things.

Comment: So do I have a seal over my heart because of my missed jummah's (even though I was unaware that I have to go)?

Comment: @mahfuzahmed Allah is the most Merciful and forgives all sins. Nobody knows about our hearts except Allah (SWT). From time to time, we all commit sins. We are fallible and should seek forgiveness for the wrongs we do. Don't rack your brains on why something has happened. Instead ask for forgives and try not to commit such acts again in the future. May Allah guide to the straight path and forgive all our sins. Allah knows best.

Comment: I will try to negotiate with my teachers to let me go jummah when school opens again InshaAllah.